# How can I make this regex shorter

Tags: regex, laravel, katakana

Let's say I have a line of text like this

> アイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲンヴガギグゲゴザジズゼゾダヂヅデドバビブベボパピプペポァィゥェォャュョッアイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナアイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲンヴガギグゲゴザジズゼゾダヂヅデドバビブベボパピプペポァィゥェォャュョッアイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナアイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲンヴガギグ

I want to verify input is katakana or not so I use regex

```
'/^[゠ ァ ア ィ イ ゥ ウ ェ エ ォ オ カ ガ キ ギ ク グ ケ ゲ コ ゴ サ ザ シ ジ ス ズ セ ゼ ソ ゾ タ ダ チ ヂ ッ ツ ヅ テ デ ト ド ナ ニ ヌ ネ ノ ハ バ パ ヒ ビ ピ フ ブ プ ヘ ベ ペ ホ ボ ポ マ ミ ム メ モ ャ ヤ ュ ユ ョ ヨ ラ リ ル レ ロ ヮ ワ ヰ ヱ ヲ ン ヴ ヵ ヶ ヷ ヸ ヹ ヺ ・ ー ヽ ヾ ヿ｟ ｠ ｡ ｢ ｣ ､ ･ ｦ ｧ ｨ ｩ ｪ ｫ ｬ ｭ ｮ ｯ ｰ ｱ ｲ ｳ ｴ ｵ ｶ ｷ ｸ ｹ ｺ ｻ ｼ ｽ ｾ ｿ ﾀ ﾁ ﾂ ﾃ ﾄ ﾅ ﾆ ﾇ ﾈ ﾉ ﾊ ﾋ ﾌ ﾍ ﾎ ﾏ ﾐ ﾑ ﾒ ﾓ ﾔ ﾕ ﾖ ﾗ ﾘ ﾙ ﾚ ﾛ ﾜ ﾝ ﾞ]+$/'
```

Is there some way to compact that?
I know its hard code, before that I used `^[ァ-ヴーｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ]+$` but it not work in laravel request rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `ァ-ヴーｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ` is correct, you just need to add `/u` to make it work.

so the correct regex code is

```
/^[ァ-ヴーｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ]+$/u
```

or an example in the laravel validation :

```
'name' => 'required|regex:/^[ァ-ヴーｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ]+$/u',
```

The `/u` modifier is for unicode support

You can also use Unicode octal as regex range, an example for Katakana is `([\u30a0-\u30ff]*)`, but in php pcre `\u` should be changed to `\x` like:

```
'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\x{30a0}-\x{30ff} ]+$/u',
```

Also, you can check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094) for other katakana and hiragana regex. Example:

Regex for matching full-width Katakana (zenkaku 全角)

```
([ァ-ン])
```

Regex for matching half-width Katakana (hankaku 半角)

```
([ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ])
```